# show fitparameters in plotlegend with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

If I do a fit on some data I got and want to plot that I also want to Show the fitparameters which I get as well as reduced chi square and r square in the legend of my plot.
What would I have to do to get this done?

Sorry if that is a trivial question, I'm new to python so I might not know or see the obvious thing.

Comment: It's totally fine to ask if you have a problem like this. But make sure you spend more words on the actual problem. What is it that prevents you from having the required text in the legend?

Comment: I just don't have any idea what I should do to achieve this...

Comment: The point is we don't know where you're stuck. This is like asking how to make a cheese cake, without any further information. It could be that you have never made any cake, so you don't even know how to prepare the bottom pastry or it could be that you have made a hundred cherry cakes already and would like to know what's different for a cheese cake.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I think my Problem might have been solved in the next comment. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to perform a fit and plot the result in a legend in matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)/5.+np.random.rand(10)

func = lambda x, a, b: a*x+b
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x,y)


plt.plot(x,y, marker="o", linestyle="none", label="data")

plt.plot(x,func(x, popt[0], popt[1]), label="fit"+str(popt))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's even more obvious than I expected.
Can I get 2 rows for one legend as well?